# Progress bar seems to be offset

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add lines on my progress bar to show milestones and I'm having a bit of trouble with getting it perfect. There always seems to be an offset and I cant figure out whats wrong with it. The progress bar below is set to 40% and the first milestone is at 40% but its so offset and if you look at the 100 its not even on the progress bar. I need a way to make this exact. Any suggestions?

```css
.progress-checkpoint {
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
    width: 1px;
    height: 29px;
    margin-top: -5px;
    color: black;
    overflow: visible;
}
.progress-checkpoint>div {
    margin-left: -19px;
    margin-top: -19px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div style="padding:50px">
  
  
  <div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="45" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 40%"><div class="progress-checkpoint" style="left: 40%;">
    <div>40</div>
    </div><div class="progress-checkpoint" style="left: 53%;">
    <div>53</div>
    </div><div class="progress-checkpoint" style="left: 67%;">
    <div>67</div>
    </div><div class="progress-checkpoint" style="left: 88%;">
    <div>88</div>
    </div><div class="progress-checkpoint" style="left: 100%;">
    <div>100</div>
    </div>        </div>
</div>
  
  
  
  </div>
```

Comment: you can add margin-left -50px on the .progress-checkpoint selector, as the absolute positioning is relying on the outter div that has the 50px of padding left and right.

Comment: @BenSewards working around an obvious problem with negative margin instead of fixing the problem itself is rather bad coding. In general negative margin devilish. You can use it and it will work, but some day it will devour your soul and break everything.
I've added the proper solution (which is fixing the alignment zero) below.

Comment: And this is why I described in my comment that the absolute positioning is relying on the incorrect div tag. Clearly you beat me to the answer :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your progressbar is properly aligned. The problem is the absolute positioning of your `.progress-checkpoint` elements.
Youre missing `position:relative` on `.progress` so the absolute positioning does start from the correct point.

Add the following to your CSS to make it work

```
.progress {
  position:relative;
}
```

In addition you need to remove `overflow:hidden` from the `.progress` Element so your text marks are not cut off.

Comment: Thanks so much worked like a charm. Sometimes you just need a second pair of eyes.